# Deploying WAR files on JBoss 6

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, war, jboss6.x

On JBoss4, I deploy my WAR files by copying it file to the  /server/default/deploy/webapps/ folder. (I had created the webapps folder myself) and everything is fine. Once the file is copied, JBoss automatically explodes the file in the tmp folder and deploys the web application.

But now that I have upgraded to JBoss 6, this method does not work. I have to extract my WAR file manually, so that JBoss can load the .so file that I have in it. i.e., if I have APP.WAR file, I have to extract APP.WAR under webapps folder and name that folder APP.WAR.

I was wondering if there is anything I have done wrong (maybe permissions) or if there is a change in JBoss 6 comparing to JBoss 4, for dealing with WAR files.

Cheers,
Reza

Comment: Are you obligated to use JBoss 6? Because if not then JBoss 7 is a ***vast*** improvement and I would highly recommend you use it instead.